# Dask Client detect local default cluster already running

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

```
from dask.distributed import Client

Client()
Client(do_not_spawn_new_if_default_address_in_use=True)  # should not spawn a new default cluster
```

Is this possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 7):

The non-public function `distributed.client._get_global_client()` will return the current client if it exists, or `None`

```
client = _get_global_client() or Client()
```

Since it is internal, the API may change without notice.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really be creating multiple clients within the same Python session. It may be worth digging deeper into why you are calling `Client()` more than once.

If you already have a Dask cluster running on the default address you could set the `DASK_SCHEDULER_ADDRESS` environment variable which will instruct the client to look there instead of creating a local cluster.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['DASK_SCHEDULER_ADDRESS'] = 'tcp://localhost:8786'

>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> Client() # Does not create a cluster
    <Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8786' processes=0 threads=0, memory=0 B>
```

Comment: My use case is simple: in jupyter notebooks sometimes I put the `Client()` call inside a cell with other code that get called several times, that is the only reason. More like a nice to have than a must have.

Comment: In that case I would recommend putting the `Client()` in a different cell that you only call once.